# GWT capture Textbox onload event

Tags: events, gwt, event-handling, onload

I have a form where the user can enter information in several Textboxes.

The textboxes are created like so -

```
GroupSection courseNumber = new GroupSection(getH4Title(""));
courseNumber.addStyleName(LUUIConstants.STYLE_SECTION);
courseNumber.addStyleName(LUUIConstants.STYLE_SECTION_DIVIDER);

// KSTextBox extends TextBox incidentally 
// I've added some custom functionality in my version of this class
KSTextBox  subjectCodeTextBox  = new KSTextBox();
KSTextBox  courseNumberTextBox = new KSTextBox();
.
.
.
addField(courseNumber, 
         COURSE + "/" + SUBJECT_AREA, 
         generateMessageInfo(LUUIConstants.SUBJECT_CODE_LABEL_KEY),
         subjectCodeTextBox);
addField(courseNumber, 
         COURSE + "/" + COURSE_NUMBER_SUFFIX,
         generateMessageInfo(LUUIConstants.COURSE_NUMBER_LABEL_KEY),
         courseNumberTextBox);
.
.
.
courseNumber.addSection(generateCrossListed_Ver_Joint_Section());
return courseNumber;
```

Here's what it looks like rendered:
[image: 2 Text boxes]

This same page on which these Text boxes are located is re-used in my application in for different scenarios; however, for one particular scenario, I need to make them read-only.

The way that I have identified this scenario is checking the title of the page.  If there is the keyword "Modify" located on the page - I do not want the user to be able to change the values that are being auto-filled in those text boxes.

I've almost achieved this by implementing this -

```
subjectCodeTextBox.addBlurHandler(new BlurHandler() {

  @Override
  public void onBlur(BlurEvent blurEvent) {
    NodeList<Element> elements = Document.get().getElementsByTagName("div");
    for (int i = 0; i < elements.getLength(); i++) {
      Element elem = elements.getItem(i);
      String innerHTML = elem.getInnerHTML();
      if (innerHTML.contains("Modify")) {
        subjectCodeTextBox.setReadOnly(true);
        courseNumberTextBox.setReadOnly(true);
      }
      break;
    }
  }
});

courseNumberTextBox.addBlurHandler(new BlurHandler() {

  @Override
  public void onBlur(BlurEvent blurEvent) {
    NodeList<Element> elements = Document.get().getElementsByTagName("div");
    for (int i = 0; i < elements.getLength(); i++) {
      Element elem = elements.getItem(i);
      String innerHTML = elem.getInnerHTML();
      if (innerHTML.contains("Modify")) {
        subjectCodeTextBox.setReadOnly(true);
        courseNumberTextBox.setReadOnly(true);
      }
      break;
    }
  }
});
```

The above code works, but it will only fire after the user has clicked in and then out of one of those 2 text boxes.  But by then, they could have changed the values and don't want that --- I'd prefer those boxes to be disabled when the page gets first rendered.

**How do I setup those textboxes to already be READONLY when the page first renders for the user?**

I figure it has something to do with the ONLOAD event, but how do I set it up properly?

Comment: I must be missing something - why are you putting that in the blur handler instead of calling it right away, or calling it as soon as the 'Modify' keyword is actually added on the page? Can't you set them readonly then?

Comment: This is part of an Enterprise Application that utilizes MVC and Spring. The rootPanel exists elsewhere in the application.  This particular class simply returns only a small segment (Section).  This same page is used in several scenarios - Modify, Create, and Retire.  The Modify keyword is inserted in a completely different class in another section where I don't have a reference to these text boxes.  It has to happen here.

Answer (score 0):

You could try coding something like:

```java
    AttachEvent.Handler attachHandler = new AttachEvent.Handler() {
    
            @Override
            public void onAttachOrDetach(AttachEvent event) {
                if (makeUnreadable) {
                    box.setReadOnly(true);
                    box.setReadOnly(true);
                }
            }
    };
    courseNumberTextBox.addAttachHandler(attachHandler);
    subjectCodeTextBox.addAttachHandler(attachHandler);
```

You may see, that I am using "makeUnreadable" flag, which you can calculate in your own way, although it must be calculated *after* "div" with "Modify" text was attached to the DOM.

Besides that, imho your way of deciding if to make boxes readable is little workaround'ish. Imagine that in the future there will be no "Modify" text, but "Edit" - then your code will not work. Same will happen when you add another language support to your app. Maybe you could figure out another way of telling the app that those fields should be unreadable?

Comment: This didn't work...worthy effort though.  Thanks for your input.

Comment: it absolutely worked for me. Maybe in your app some widgets are not attached to the DOM correctly or so. Try to run this example on a simple RootPanel.